# Grammar and use of すればしただけ

Tags: syntax

I am having difficulty understanding this sentence. A comparison is being made to the effect that as the cruel feeling flowed out I washed the sea water out of the pants. But I am not sure about this. I understand that the だけ is the equivalent of ほど. But the sentence remains unclear to me.

> そうすればしただけ、リエを泣かせた昼間の残酷な気持ちが流れ出ていくかのように、私はできるだけ丁寧に海水パンツを洗った．

Answer (score 3):

This ～ば～だけ is almost the same as [the ～ば～ほど construction](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%B0%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9-bahodo/) meaning "the more ～(, the more ～)".

This そうすれば and した refer to something mentioned in the latter half of the sentence, namely 丁寧に海水パンツを洗う. 海水パンツ (commonly abbreviated as [海パン](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B5%B7%E3%83%91%E3%83%B3)) is a single phrase meaning *swim shorts*.

> そうすればしただけ、リエを泣かせた昼間の残酷な気持ちが流れ出ていくかのように、私はできるだけ丁寧に海水パンツを洗った。
>   I washed my swim shorts as carefully as possible, thinking the more I washed it, the more my cruel feelings during the day that had made Rie cry would flow out of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was wondering whether you think another possible translation of this sentence might be: "By washing the swim shorts as carefully as possible, I thought the cruel feeling .... would flow out of them" I ask this because the Jisho dictionary gives a secondary translation of だけ as "as“　(e.g. as soon as, as much as"? Or would this distort the meaning? Thank you again.

Comment: @Robert Yes I think that's a fine translation, if not the most literal.